# Passing large amount of data between pages wont load the page in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, parameter-passing, textblock

I'm trying to pass some text between pages to a textblock. It works fine with small amount of data, but with large amount of data the page won't load.

Page 1:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/DetailPage.xaml?gameGuide=" + gameGuide, UriKind.Relative));
```

Page 2:

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("gameGuide", out gameGuide))
    guideTxtBlk.Text = gameGuide;
```

The data source is from a XML file which I'm downloading to Page 1.

Here is the amount of data that work:

> In the level "Project Nova", after you fight the British and
>   escape, you must set an explosive. Make sure you clear out all the
>   enemies before planting it. There should be a Mosin–Nagant gun after
>   killing the enemies in the first room. This should help you clear out
>   the enemies in the second room, especially the enemies on the higher
>   walkways. You can shoot through the metal gratings. After setting the
>   explosive, shoot the highlighted beam and make your way out. As you
>   head out, there will be an enemy outside the door on your right and
>   another coming on your left. Kill these two and then sprint down the
>   walkway. There will be a few more enemies climbing onto the ship but
>   you should have no issues killing them and proceeding. A last enemy
>   should be up high so be forewarned. If you die at any time during this
>   run, you may still have enough time to make it, as long as there is
>   2:15 left on the timer.

Here is the one that don't work:

> This is easiest to do on Recruit difficulty and is done on the level
>   "WMD". You will be in control of the dispatcher in the SR71 plane and
>   a soldier on the ground, switching between them from time to time. To
>   zoom in you press (LT) and to zoom out you press (RT). To command your
>   squad on where to go, press (A) on the location. Use (LS) to move the
>   cursor around the area. After you find the squad on your screen, you
>   will be given an insertion point that is to the east of you labeled
>   "1602". After you hear that vehicles are coming in from the north, you
>   will be told to put your team into the building labeled "Safe House".
>   Select the Safe House with (A). You will be put into the soldier’s
>   scenario to kill the enemies entering the house. After the encounter
>   with the enemies that entered the building, you will be put back into
>   the hands of the dispatcher. Make sure all 4 of your teammates are
>   alive on the screen. After this, select the back of the Safe House
>   building. To the right you will see two enemies next to a barrel.
>   Scroll over these enemies and select them with (A) to have your team
>   attack them. Directly behind them is an objective point. Select the
>   objective point so that your team moves to this location. After that,
>   you will be given another insertion point just below this one. You
>   will see bushes halfway between your current location and the
>   objective point. Select the bushes with (A) to have your team move
>   there (you should be 500-600 away from the insertion point).
>   Immediately after they have moved, your dispatch will tell you that a
>   large group of enemies is coming around. You will be told to hold down
>   (RS) to make your team go into a prone position and not be seen by the
>   enemies. After you get the all clear, move your team to the objective
>   directly in front of them and you will be given an objective labeled
>   "Barracks". The on screen reticule should turn red, so select the
>   Barracks with (A) to have them move into position. Now you will be put
>   back into the view of the soldier. Eliminate all the enemies found
>   inside of the building and be sure to be in front to take as much of
>   the fire that is shot at you and your teammates. At the end of all
>   this, you should have all four of your teammates with you. You need to
>   clear the last room, plant and detonate the C4 and make it through the
>   barracks. You will be given a new insertion point once you leave the
>   barracks, so guide your team there. When you have reached the second
>   insertion point outside of the building, you have safely guided the
>   squad without killing them. Make sure that while you are controlling
>   your team, no vehicles that drive by see you as your team on the
>   ground will be eliminated immediately. If they are eliminated, you
>   will need to restart the whole mission over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a maximum length for a URI. I think it is somewhere around 2000 characters. You should probably adopt a different method to pass the data between the pages.  Use a global variable, put the data in the ViewModel, or save and retrieve from PhoneApplicationService/IsolatedStorage are some options.

Comment: Thanks, I used GlobalVariable and is working great. but now the textblock cuts the text. I remember seen a workaround somewhere.